# Sponsored Transactions on Solana

Tags: transactions

Gm guys, is there anything like https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2711#sponsored-transactions for Solana?

Shortly: a way for a program to pay for the transaction fees of selected pubkeys (whitelisted users) interacting with selected programs (whitelisted programs)

The goal would be to have a user interacting with a dapp without worrying about fees (interesting usecase for web3 gaming)

Answer (score 1):

In Solana transactions any signer can be the fee payer. So one way that you could do this would be to write an API with access to a fee paying keypair, and have it produce transactions with that keypair as the fee payer and as a signer. Depending on your needs you could have it return partially signed transactions to the user (to have them then sign and submit them using their connected wallet), or you could just have it submit the transactions if you don't need the user's signature.

I'm not familiar with that EIP to compare but hopefully that helps you do what you want to do on Solana.